# Error: fetch failed with status code 403

Tags: npm, fiddler, firewall, http-status-code-403

My npm build worked perfectly yesterday, but it began failing hard today. I see the following error in my console and logs:

Error: fetch failed with status code 403

- When I try to fetch an npm package with any web browser it succeeds.
- But when I try to fetch that same npm package with `npm i`, it fails with the aforementioned `403` Forbidden error. My corporate firewall is clearly blocking `registry.npmjs.org`.

When I observe these web requests in Fiddler, I can see differences. I've also figured out how to fix the web request that isn't working.

[image]

Does anyone know why npm is working differently today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Root Cause: The corporate firewall was blacklisting `registry.npmjs.org`'s IP address (`151.101.20.162`):

[image]

- Solution: The IT department removed this IP address from its blacklist.